# SSRS: Add Name to Sheet after export to Excel

Tags: ssrs-2012

I commonly export SSRS Reports to multiple Sheets in Excel and email them to appropriate Users.

In those Excel spreadsheets, each Sheet has its own Name based on the Page Name Property of the Tablix [if each sheet gets its data from a separate Tablix] - or based on the Name of the Grouping.

In a new report, I have a 'Criteria' Text Box that exports out to the first Sheet in Excel - but it is being named 'Sheet1' - and I would like that Sheet in Excel to be named 'Criteria'. I have not been able to achieve that.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!!

Comment: I have done that a long while ago.. just dont have the syntax approach with me.. please review this .. http://reese-consulting.com/export-group-name-in-ssrs-2008-to-worksheet-tab-name-in-excel/   - It might be helpful

Comment: @goofyui - thanks! Most of the information you point to has to do with naming the Sheets based on Tablix Grouping. What answered my question [in one of the links] was using the 'Initial Page Name' Property of the Report. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to links provided by @goofyui, I found a solution using the 'Initial Page Name' Property of the Report Object and giving it a value of "Criteria".